# Appending a character to a string, deleting and printing the string in c

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that appends a letter you give to the current string that it has. I am having a problem on almost every area, as if I try to add a letter, it gives me a "Segmentation fault". I have added a comment what each section should do, I'd appreciate some help on this project.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

        int main(void) {
        int choice;
        char str[20];
        char str1;

    while(1) {
        printf("Give your choice: "); //Asks the choice from the menu
        scanf("%i", &choice);

        if(choice == 1) { //This choice adds a letter to the (empty) string
            printf("Give a letter: ");
            scanf("%s", str); 
            strcat(str, str1); }

        else if(choice == 2) { //choice 2 clears the string
            printf("");
            scanf("%s", str1); }

        else if(choice == 3) { //choice 3 prints what's in the string
            printf("%s", str1); }

        else { //if choice is wrong, it ends the program
            printf("Faulty input!\n");
            break; }

        }   }
```

Thank you!

Comment: And what compiler warnings do you get when you compile this code?

Comment: You are treating `str1` as `char *` instead of `char`.

Comment: You're going to get a *lot* of warnings here because there's a number of operations going on here that are invalid but the compiler's doing it anyway because it's not told to look for mistakes. `-Wall` when compiling.

Comment: Segmentation fault (Core dumped) @AndrewHenle

Comment: Two warnings my man @tadman 
I'm pretty new to C, I have tried to search for help elsewhere before asking, but couldn't find a solution, so I figured this would be the best place to ask.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being new to C. The first thing you'll need to learn is that C will do exactly what you ask, even if what you ask makes no sense or will crash your program. It's your absolute responsibility to write correct C code. Turning on warnings with `-Wall` will help identify mistakes, and that's the second thing you need to learn: the compiler will only help *if you ask for help*. Otherwise it just keeps quiet. They say "C gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot", and if you didn't know you could shoot yourself with rope you should have read the docs more closely.

Comment: Here you're calling `strcat(char*, char)` which is not a supported operation. You'll need to capture that to a `char*` or find a different method for appending to a string.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to work around it a bit. First time trying to do this kind of a excerce, but it's going forward :)

Comment: If you are using gcc or clang, add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` as compiler options to *enable compiler warnings*. If you are using VS, add `/W3`. Then do not accept code until it compiles without warning. The compilers will tell you exactly which line has potential problems. Let the compiler help you (it's actually quite good). If you simply address each warning -- you will save yourself hours of debugging.

Answer (score 2):

> This choice adds a letter to the (empty) string

```
scanf("%s", str); 
strcat(str, str1);
```

Here you are not adding the letter to existing string instead clearing the string and retaking the input.
Also passing `char` to `strcat` leads to undefined behavior as `strcat` expects its arguments to be `char *` and *null* terminated.

---

Change it to as below.

```
scanf(" %c", &str1); //Takes single char
int len = strlen(str); //Finds the length
str[len] = str1; // Appends the char
str[len + 1] = '\0'; //null terminates the string
```

Comment: I changed the selection 3 to:
`printf("%d\n", str1);`
After typing a letter in choice one I try to print it,
But it prints out a number, any clues why it does that?

Comment: Use `%c` ,  `%d` is for integer thus you are printing ASCII value.

Comment: If I change it to `%s` , it gives me Segmentation fault.

Comment: `%s` is for string not for char, use `%c`.

Comment: Thanks! One more question; Is it possible to edit the code so after I give my first letter, if I call the choice 1 again, it adds the new letter behind the first one? Currently it overwrites it every time I call it. Thank you

Comment: Initialise the local variable `char str[20] ={0};`.

Comment: It will still overwrite the given letter. My idea was to append the next letter to the string. So it would be like a -> (input b) ab -> (input c) abc etc.
Thanks!